# As amounts of the 2 charges are given only by symbols , how do I determine the amount of charge of \$Q=CV~\$ of cylindrical capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitance

[image]

The cylinder exists with the height \$d\$ and the radius \$a\$

The cylindrical shell surrounds that cylinder with the cocentric radius \$b\$

The space between of it has been filled with the dielectric of  \$  \epsilon_{}  \$

\$Q_{1},Q_{2} \$ are given to the inner,outer conductors respectively.

I want to calculate the capacitance of this capacitor.

First things to first, the electric field inside the dielectric is easily obtained by

$$   \left( 2\pi r  \cdot d \right)  E_{r}  = \frac{  Q_{1}  }{ \epsilon_{}    }  $$

$$  E_{r} =  \frac{  Q_{1}  }{   2\pi rd \epsilon_{}  }  $$

To find out the voltage between the conductors,

$$ V= -\int_{b }^{ a} \frac{  Q_{1}  }{   2\pi rd \epsilon_{}  } \,dr   $$

$$ =   \int_{a }^{ b} \frac{  Q_{1}  }{   2\pi rd \epsilon_{}  } \,dr$$

$$ =  \frac{  Q_{1}  }{ 2\pi d \epsilon_{}   }  \int_{a }^{ b} \frac{ 1  }{  r} \,dr$$

$$ =   \frac{  Q_{1}  }{ 2\pi d \epsilon_{}   }  \ln\left(  b/a \right)   $$

The problem begins from here.

I attempted to use the general formula \$CV=Q\$

$$  C=\frac{  Q  }{ V   }  $$

How the value of \$Q\$ is determined?

As the distributions of charges are one of the  typical patterns like \$0<Q_{1}=-Q_{2}  \leftrightarrow \left| Q_{1} \right| =\left| Q_{2} \right|   \$

I can determine \$Q=Q_{1}\$ but how about it is not guaranteed of \$0<Q_{1}=-Q_{2}  \leftrightarrow \left| Q_{1} \right| =\left| Q_{2} \right|   \$

Or can I assume \$ \left| Q_{1} \right| =\left| Q_{2} \right|\$ forcefully?

By the way I assumed that the any electric field is vertical against the surface of the flank of the inner cylinder. Is it correct?

The inner conductor is given \$Q_{1}\$ but the distribution of the charges is undefined.

Comment: I do not see the problem: in your formulas you have V as a function of Q, so if you put in the fraction Q and V, then Q will rule out and disappear whatever its value. The only assumption is that Q is the same but with opposite sign on the two surfaces of the cylinder. --  and yes, the electric field is vertical, except at the two ends where you have some deviation from it.

Comment: From gauss law , outer cylinder has charges -Q1 on inner surface and Q2+Q1 on outer surface , so you can safely assume Q=Q1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitor in a static electricity apparatus is sometimes just
a sphere on a stick.   The capacitance of such an item is calculated
with the assumption of a very-large-container around the sphere, which
is grounded.   This 'ground at infinity' means that a second electrode is
assumed to exist, with access to whatever charge it 'needs',and that
means the second electrode carries equal and opposite charge to the first.   Exact dimensions of an outer container, if it is sufficiently
large, are irrelevant (the E-fields fall off with distance, all the capacitive field energy is near the sphere on the stick).

In circuits (not static electricity) a capacitor has two terminals,
but the same assumption can be made, that the (outer, usually) electrode is
grounded, i.e. has access to an inexhaustible charge reservoir, and
thus will always take on an equal and opposite charge to the inner.

Since the imbalance of charge on the two plates does not change the
capacitance (which is a dimension-geometry-and-materials dependent number), you
can safely assume that the outer holds charge -*Q1*, if that
helps the calculation.   Then the 'Q'  of your formula  is the
charge on the inner electrode, *Q1*.